# Upgrading Webpack from 1x to 3x and Babel

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to update an older code base to more current stuff - nearly done. Now I just need to update the webpack and babel stuff. The old code base is using Webpack 1x. I want to update to Webpack 3x and discovering a handful of errors with babel-loader, so I'm assuming updateing babel should theoretically fix the problem. I'm just not sure what to update babel to?

Here is a list of the current pertinent devDependencies

```
"babel-core": "^6.7.2",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
  "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
  "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.2",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
  "webpack": "^1.12.14",
  "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
  "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
```

Any suggestions on what to update all the babel stuff to. I've installed babel-loader v7x and that is throwing the errors. It seems Webpack 3x requires Babel-loader 7x or greater.

UPDATE
Here are the errors

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed: TypeError: fileSystem.statSync is not a function
    at module.exports (/home/david/tutorials/react/mgbp/mgbp-default-refactored/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/utils/exists.js:7:25)
    at find (/home/david/tutorials/react/mgbp/mgbp-default-refactored/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/resolve-rc.js:13:9)
    at Object.module.exports (/home/david/tutorials/react/mgbp/mgbp-default-refactored/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:111:132)
 @ multi main
```

Comment: "discovering a handful of errors with babel-loader" What are the errors? "that is throwing the errors" What are the errors?

Comment: @loganfsmyth - please look at the update, posted the errors thx!

Comment: I'm confused, you say you want to update to Webpack 3, but your `package.json` still has `"webpack": "^1.12.14",`. That error is because you're using the new `babel-loader` on Webpack 1.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - sorry got pulled away there. Yes, you are correct. Too much testing and lost track of where I was. I've got babel updated versions in and reinstalled webpack 3.5.6 and that took care of the errors.